# Redirecting folder from one domain to another using .htaccess 301 redirect

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to figure out a rewrite so as to redirect a directory and all of it's files & subdirectories from one domain to another.

Here is what I would like to achieve:

`olddomain.com/oldfolder/*`

to

`http://newdomain.com/newfolder/*`

Currently I am using the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomain.com/newfolder/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This works for www.olddomain.com but not also for olddomain.com.  What's the best way to achieve this?
Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^oldfolder/(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/newfolder/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```